# Credible intervals with parameter near boundary

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

When doing Bayesian inference on a parameter that is bounded, often we use priors that approach 0 as the parameter approaches the boundary. For example, when estimating $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for normal data, the conjugate prior on $\sigma^2$ is inverse $\chi^2$ for some choice of hyperparameters. This prior has density 0 at $\sigma^2=0$, which is the boundary value. Under a conjugate prior on $\mu$ as well, resulting marginal posterior for $\sigma^2$ is also inverse $\chi^2$. Since the posterior has density approaching 0 for any $\sigma^2$ very close to 0, it seems that for any $\sigma^2$ sufficiently close to 0, equal-tailed credible intervals (but presumably also HDPI?) will not have nominal frequentist coverage. (In simulations, I am seeing this behavior in a slightly more complicated, but similar, estimation problem with a bounded variance component.)

**How can I construct a credible interval that retains nominal frequentist coverage when the parameter is near the boundary?**

Comment: The improper prior $\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)\propto 1/\sigma^2$ leads to equal-tailed credible intervals with frequentist coverage at the nominal level for both $\mu$ and $\sigma$.  I'm not sure if this would be true also for the corresponding HPD intervals.

Comment: One might conceive of the issue not being vanishing of the density, but merely choice of parameterization: you can always reparameterize so that the density remains finite (or even blows up!) at the boundary.

Comment: @whuber thanks. In the case I'm actually interested in, I am actually using the joint Jeffreys prior on a location and scale parameter, so that particular prior would be invariant.

Comment: @JarleTufto That's interesting. The case I'm actually dealing with does show less than nominal coverage for both equal-tailed and HPD intervals. Specifically, I'm using the joint Jeffreys prior on the location and scale parameters of a meta-analysis, so essentially a normal distribution with inverse-variance weights.

Comment: Why do you need to have nominal frequentist coverage for a credible interval where you have used an arbitrary prior? (I guess that I am pointing towards @whuber's comment.) I would want good coverage when you use the posterior of one iteration of Bayesian analysis as the prior of the follow-on experiment.

Comment: @MichaelLew, thanks. I chose the Jeffreys prior specifically for its frequentist properties, in particular the fact that it removes the $O(n^{-1})$ bias in the MLE for exponential family distributions.

Comment: OK, so you chose an arbitrary prior to get good frequentist coverage where the parameter is small or large. Does that not answer your own question? (I'd still be more concerned with the performance where there is information in the prior...)

Comment: @MichaelLew, I'm not sure why you describe it as an arbitrary prior. I am not aware of any other prior that has the property I note above. I'm not sure how this answers my question. Can you clarify?

Comment: If you choose a prior for its frequentist properties then the answer to your question is to choose an optimal prior. It may be the Jeffries prior. (Arbitrary: Based on or subject to individual judgment or preference.)